# In Refinery CMS, how can I apply page-part changes to existing pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I found the same question discussed in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/sFGaH6lGkLM), but the FAQ page it references is dead and the final answer looks case-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty simple. Following [the solution given in the Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/refinery-cms/sFGaH6lGkLM/iDxSljJjogsJ), I used the Rails console. For future reference, here's the full routine for adding a new page-part and applying to all existing pages:

First add the new page-page(s) in your refinery pages config file. This is detailed here in the [Refinery docs](http://refinerycms.com/guides/changing-page-parts). In this example, I add a page-part called "epigraph":

```
  # Configure global page default parts
  config.default_parts =  ["Body", "Side Body", "Epigraph"]

  # Configure whether to allow adding new page parts
  config.new_page_parts = true
```

Then update your view file (`app\views\refinery\pages\show.html.erb` if you're using the default) to include the new page-part. In my case:

```
   <div class="epigraph">
      <%= raw @page.content_for(:epigraph) %>
   </div>
```

Then, from the [rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console), run this map command **for each new page-part** you add. For my example:

```
Refinery::Page.all.map {|p| p.parts.create(:title => "Epigraph", :position => 2) unless p.parts.exists?(:title => "Epigraph") }
```

I'm assuming the position parameter specifies where to place among the tabs on the edit page and that it counts from 0. But not absolutely sure.